# Why remote library works but local library throws error?

Tags: reactjs

I am building a component library, and install it as a local package, but it throws an error when I use react Hooks.

```
import React from "react";
import { useSelector } from "react-redux";

export default function Info() {
  const name = useSelector((state) => state.account.name);
  return (
    <>
      <ul>
        <li>name: {name}</li>
      </ul>
    </>
  );
}
```

Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component.

Then I upload this component library to remote, install it again, it solved.
But I still didn't know why...
Could anyone explain it?

My package.json

```
{
  "name": "package",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "main": "dist/index.js",
  "babel": {
    "presets": [
      [
        "react-app"
      ]
    ]
  },
  "dependencies": {},
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "compile": "rm -rf dist && mkdir dist && cross-env NODE_ENV=development babel ./src/components -d dist --copy-files"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "^7.12.0",
    "cross-env": "^7.0.2",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.1",
    "redux": "^4.0.5",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",
    "react": "^16.14.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.14.0",
    "react-scripts": "3.4.3",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^9.3.2",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^7.1.2"
  },
}
```

Is there any difference behavior between the local package and remote package?
I read many articles, I guess it might be the multiple instances of React.
But why remote package wouldn't have this problem?

Articles I read:
[Hooks + multiple instances of React #13991](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/13991)
[Invalid Hook Call Warning](https://reactjs.org/warnings/invalid-hook-call-warning.html)

Comment: please show your code

Answer (score 0):

remove the brackets

> const name = useSelector(state => state.account.name);

Answer (score 0):

Add curly braces, and remove name in the end.. as you are trying to destructure the state.

```
const { name } = useSelector((state) => state.account);
```